# Ruby version for Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

Can Chef support newer versions of Ruby i.e. 2.0.0?
If not , is there a reason why?

In the documentation it specified up to 1.9.2
https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/System+Requirements+with+install (dead link)

Comment: If you install chef using the omnibus installer it comes with its own embedded copy of ruby. Best to use this and keep a clean separation between Ruby for running apps and ruby for running chef.

Answer (score 5):

Chef 11.6+ supports Ruby 2.0. Versions less than that will only work on Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.

Sources:

- I work for Opscode
- I use Chef on Ruby 2.0, 1.9, and 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Documentation might need some updating. Chef supports ruby 2.0 according to this blogpost

http://www.opscode.com/blog/2013/09/03/chef-10-28-0-released/

Answer (score 0):

Find the latest requirements at https://docs.chef.io/chef_system_requirements.html

[Currently](https://github.com/chef/chef-web-docs/blob/cbcb945bb00c41ab94a07ebe49143ed4fa5b68a2/chef_master/source/chef_system_requirements.rst#chef-client), Ruby 2.2.2 (or higher)